# What happens to an upvote attempt by users without the upvote privilege?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

When a user with less than 15 rep attempts to upvote a question, they get the following message.

> Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

However, what happens when they reach 15 rep? Will their vote be cast automatically or do they need to cast them manually if they wish to?